# Why fragments are not recreated in viewpager when the activity is recreated?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

In my application I am using viewpager with tablayout.When the app is in background for longtime, The activity is recreated but the fragments are not recreated, so the data coming from the service is not getting updated on the UI.

Comment: Any update? I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

move ui update logic to `onResume`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // call api for getting data
    // call ui processing method
}
```